# Capturing still images using AMCAP?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, webcam, video-capture

I am developer from *nix world so any pointers will be helpful.

I am using the AMCAP SDK example and have to capture live preview and still images. I understood the code for getting live preview. Now how can I capture an image at runtime from the gcap data structure ? Mind you the application has to do some real time image processing on the captured image and return the out immediately. So I don't want to save the live preview as avi and extract a frame from it.

Regards
Ankur

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about doing it with the amcap example. However, if you are trying to process the images from the stream, check out [this CodeProject example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/VideoImageGrabber.aspx). IMO this example is far simpler and clearer than amcap or any other sample from the Microsoft SDK.